# Наследование шаблонных и абстрактных классов

Tags: c++, наследование

У меня появилась проблема с наследованием абстрактной структуры и с переопределением функции.

У меня есть структура inheritorStruct, в которой есть еще одна структура internalStruct и функция getTest, которая возвращает указатель на internalStruct.
Структур на подобии inheritorStruct множество и в каждой структуре своя реализация internalStruct и функции getTest. Так же все структуры являются шаблонными.

У меня была идея сделать в abstractStruct прототип на структуру internalStruct и виртуальную функцию getTest.

```
template <typename T>
struct abstractStruct {
public:
    template<typename T>struct internalStruct;
    virtual internalStruct<T>* getTest(const int t) = 0;
};
```

а уже в inheritorStruct сделать реализацию internalStruct и функции getTest.
Для проверки сделал так же конструктор inheritorStruct

```
template<typename T>
struct inheritorStruct : public abstractStruct<T> {
    template<typename T>
    struct internalStruct {
        T t;
        internalStruct(T t) : t(t) {}
    };
    internalStruct<T>* getTest(const int t) override {
        return new internalStruct<int>(t);
    }
    inheritorStruct(int f) {
        internalStruct<T>* temp = getTest(214);
        cout << temp->t << endl;
    }
};
```

и код в main()

```
int main() {
    inheritorStruct<int> test(190);
}
```

Подчеркивает реализацию getTest в inheritorStruct. А так же переменную test.

`1) E0322   использование объекта абстрактного типа класса "inheritorStruct<int>" не допускается`

`2) C2555   inheritorStruct<int>::getTest: возвращаемый тип перегруженной виртуальной функции отличается от "abstractStruct<T>::getTest" и не является ковариантным`

Подскажите, как исправить ошибки тк в интернете не нашел решения. Или скажите как по другому все это реализовать.

Comment: Тут проблема в том, что у вас получается два несвязанных неродственных класса `abstractStruct::internalStruct` и `inheritorStruct::internalStruct`. Выносите `internalStruct` наружу.

Comment: вы все тут смешали: каша получилась

Comment: @user7860670 мне нужно чтобы об internalStruct  знали только abstractStruct и его наследники и больше никто. И так же реализация internalStruct у всех разная должна быть. Например в 1 наследнике будет одна переменная, а в другом уже 2. Хотя может и стоит для каждого наследника просто свой internalStruct сделать.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вау ну спасибо за помощь! Есть несколько структур у каждой есть внутренняя структура и 1 функция. Но они реализованы у каждой структуры по разному. Вот я и решил в абстрактный класс вынести структуру и метод. А в наследниках переопределять. По факту чтобы мне помочь надо подсказать как структуру в наследниках правильно переопределять и где ошибка в переопределении методаю

Comment: ну а для чего наследование? Если в базовом классе определите шаблон структуры, то можете инстанцировать в производных классах. А по факту вам немного трудно помочь, потому что не до конца ясны ваши намерения.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan объясните то что написали во 2 предложении. Как это определить шаблон структуры? И еще я не знаю куда проще объяснить то что мне надо.

Comment: Например. Есть 2 человека (это 2 структуры) у каждого есть разные предметы (internalStruct), которые только они могут использовать и предметы разные. Так же эти люди по разному используют предмет (функция getTest). И тк это люди и по факту имеют общее.(предмет и функция действия над предметом) то я хочу их объединить в одну структуру. Надеюсь понятней стало

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а вот сейчас реально извеняюсь. Посмотрел продолжение и подчеркнул для себя совет. Тип internalStruct зависит от inheritorStruct. Вопрос остается открым. Если я захочу сделать inheritorStruct1 или еще больше. Мне надо чтобы internalStruct в каждой inheritor структуре был разный. (Больше переменных, конструктор другой) и все вопрос будет закрыт и я поблагодарю вас за помощь.

Comment: вы всегда можете перегрузить новые конструкторы в `internalStruct,`  добавить члены и методы. Также всегда можете в новом классе определить другую структуру `internalStruct` или его **наследника**. Также можете добавлять методы  и члены в абстрактном классе(думаю так лучше),  для получения нужной абстакции. Вы же все таки его наследуете, а не   internalStruct. Вы также можете определить нужные производные структуры от  internalStruct прямо после его определения в базовом классе. Вы также можете вынести эту структуру из области охватываемости базового и сделать шаблонным. Не знаю что вам нужно

Comment: Можете просто перегрузить шаблонный конструктор в  `internalStruct,` а  не саму структуру сделать шаблонным. Вообшем вариантов очень много. Все зависит от конкретной задачи, и даже при конкретной задаче вариантов очень много _ все не перечислить... **Желаю удачи**

Comment: А вот как перегрузить структуру? Можете пожалуйста в виде ответа выложить. И я приму его

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103682/discussion-between---and-ar-hovsepyan).